# N soliton solution KdV equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, soliton-theory

I find many references to the "N-soliton" solution to the KdV equation

$$
 u_{t} - uu_{x} + u_{xxx} = 0
$$

of the form $u(x, 0) = N(N+1) \operatorname{sech}^{2}(x)$. However, I require the $N$ soliton solution for

$$
u_{t} + uu_{x} + u_{xxx} = 0
$$
instead. Does anyone know the answer or know a paper where this is found?

Comment: Because that second term is 'quadratic', if $u$ satisfies $u_t-uu_x+u_{xxx}=0$ then $v=-u$ satisfies $v_t+vv_x+v_{xxx}=0$, so the equations are equivalent.